# Browse subcolumns, but discard some

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I have a table (or view) in my PostgreSQL database and want to do the following:
Query the table and feed a function in my application subsequent n-tuples of rows from the query, but only those that satisfy some condition. I can do the n-tuple listing using a cursor, but I don't know how to do the condition checking on database level.

For example, the query returns:

```
3
2
4
2
0
1
4
6
2
```

And I want triples of even numbers. Here, they would be:

```
(2,4,2) (4,2,0) (4,6,2)
```

Obviously, I cannot discard the odd numbers from the query result. Instead using cursor, a query returning arrays in similar manner would also be acceptable solution, but I don't have any good idea how to use them to do this.

Of course, I could check it at application level, but I think it'd be cleaner to do it on database level. Is it possible?

Comment: You just want three "consecutive" records that all have an even value for the column? BTW: you don't need cursors.

Comment: This is just simple example, I didn't want to go in details of my tables, but basically, yes. In general, I want to evaluate a predicate on each n consecutive rows and return them only if the predicate evaluates to true.

Comment: Take a look at window funtions, particularly `lag()` , `lead()` and `rank()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the [window function `lead()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) ([as mentioned by @wildplasser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595177/browse-subcolumns-but-discard-some/22596325?noredirect=1#comment34401071_22595177)):

```
SELECT *
FROM  (
  SELECT tbl_id, i AS i1
       , lead(i)    OVER (ORDER BY tbl_id) AS i2
       , lead(i, 2) OVER (ORDER BY tbl_id) AS i3
  FROM   tbl
  ) sub
WHERE  i1%2 = 0
AND    i2%2 = 0
AND    i3%2 = 0;
```

There is no natural order of rows - assuming you want to order by `tbl_id` in the example.
[`%` .. modulo operator](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-OP-TABLE)

[**SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/9da79/1)

Comment: Window functions, that's what I needed! I didn't know such thing existed. Thank you very much!

Comment: Well, I told you that they existed, so you could have known.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use an array aggregate for this instead of using `lag`:

```
SELECT
  a[1] a1, a[2] a2, a[3] a3
FROM (
  SELECT
    array_agg(i) OVER (ORDER BY tbl_id ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
  FROM
    tbl
) x(a)
WHERE a[1] % 2 = 0 AND a[2] % 2 = 0 AND a[3] % 2 = 0;
```

No idea if this'll be better, worse, or the same as Erwin's answer, just putting it in for completeness.

Comment: EXPLAIN command in PostgreSQL reveals that they are the same. Just for sompleteness- :)

Comment: Certainly shorter syntax for long arrays.